# Traducción de "garden path sentence"

Tags: traducción

Una ["garden path sentence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) es una frase gramaticalmente correcta que está construida de modo que lo más probable es que el lector la interprete de un modo incorrecto y se encuentre con una frase sin sentido o con un significado extraño, lo que le lleva a reanalizar la frase para encontrar el significado real. Por ejemplo, en inglés, la frase "**The old man the boat**" normalmente es procesada / traducida como "El anciano hombre el barco" - como eso no tiene sentido, se reinterpreta "man" como verbo y la frase adquiere ya sentido ("El anciano está a cargo del barco").
¿Cómo se diría en español "golden path sentence"?

Comment: Después de una vista/búsqueda rápida, no he encontrado ninguna traducción común al español. Oración ambigua no es, ya que la(s) interpretación(es) válida(s) no es(son) percibida(s) hasta después de interpretar la oración de forma sintácticamente invalida. Parece que el holandés dice algo como una oración engañante, que no quedaría mal si precisas un término breve (habría falta explicación, pero lo mismo pasa con el inglés). A ver si alguien puede encontrar algo más usado.

Comment: Qué concepto tan interesante -iba a hacer un _garden path_ pero no me salió ninguno-.

Comment: Qué gracia, porque en español existe la expresión "meterse en un jardín" (enredarse innecesariamente en el discurso), que no es lo mismo, pero también alude a un discurso fallido (en este caso por exceso).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*garden path* se traduce en este contexto como *vía muerta*. Entonces *garden path model* es *modelo de vía muerta*, y *garden path sentence* es *oración de vía muerta*.

- [Ejemplo de uso 1](http://www.scielo.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0071-17132015000100001&script=sci_arttext)

> El estudio sobre el procesamiento de oraciones con ambigüedad temporal, conocidas también como "oraciones de vía muerta" o *garden path sentences*

- [Ejemplo de uso 2](https://www.redib.org/recursos/Record/oai_articulo129934-procesamiento-oraciones-ambiguas-via-muerta-envejecimiento-estudio-experimental)

> **Resumen** Se presentan los resultados de un estudio experimental cuyo propósito es determinar si el envejecimiento cognitivo normal afecta o no el procesamiento de oraciones ambiguas de "vía muerta" que llevan a cabo los adultos mayores.
>
> **Abstract** This article presents the results of an experimental study whose purpose is to determine whether normal cognitive aging affects older adult's processing of ambiguous "garden path" sentences.

- [Ejemplo de uso 3](http://www.psicocode.com/resumenes/6lenguaje.pdf)

> Este tipo de oraciones se llaman de vía muerta, pues
>   inducen al lector a optar inicialmente por un camino erróneo, y son muy útiles en el
>   estudio empírico del análisis sintáctico.

Ejemplos de oraciones de vía muerta en castellano extraídas de esos artículos:

- *Mientras la joven montaba el potro fue robado de las caballerizas*
- *A Pedro le secuestró un gangster su novia*

Answer (score 1):

También existe el adjetivo ***equívoco***.

Aunque el diccionario de la RAE solo da un significado (*"que puede interpretarse en varios sentidos, o dar ocasión a juicios diversos"*), la [segunda acepción de Oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/es/definicion/espanol/equivoco) es común en el uso del español: "***que promueve o dirige a equivocación***".